# How does the Riemannian Hessian change when changing the metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold with metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x$, and consider a smooth function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that we consider another Riemannian metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x'$ on $M$. Then we know that for each $x\in M$ there exists a unique positive definite linear operator $P_x:T_xM\to T_xM$ such that
\begin{equation}
\langle u,v\rangle_x' = \langle u,P_xv\rangle_x \qquad \forall u,v\in T_xM.
\end{equation}
Knowing $P_x$, one can derive the Riemannian gradient of $f$ with respect to the metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x'$ from the Riemannian gradient with respect to the metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x$ as
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{grad}^{\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x'} f(X) = P_x^{-1}\mathrm{grad}^{\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x} f(X).
\end{equation}
Does a similar relation hold also for the Riemannian Hessian, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Hess}^{\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x'} f(X) = P_x^{-1} \circ \mathrm{Hess}^{\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x} f(X)?
\end{equation}

I tried by proving that $\bar{\nabla}_UV:= P_x^{-1}\nabla_UP_xV$ is the Levi-Civita connection w.r.t $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x'$, where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection w.r.t. $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x$, but I think that this is not true (I proved that $\bar{\nabla}$ is a connection, but don't see a way to prove symmetry and compatibility with the metric). Can we say something at least in the case where $M$ is an embedded submanifold of a Euclidean space $E$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x= \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ , $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x' = \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle'$  are two metrics of the embedding space?

Comment: The answer is no. The differential of a function is independent of the metric, and the gradient is the gradient multiplied by the metric tensor (what you call $P_x$). Therefore, the dependence of the gradient on the metric is straightforward.


On the other hand, the Hessian is defined to be the covariant derivative of the gradient (or differential) of a function. The covariant derivative is defined using the first order partial derivatives of the metric. So, not surprisingly, if you change the metric, the change in the Hessian depends on the derivatives of the metrics.

Comment: That was my intuition too. But can we say something if the metric is always the same, that is, if we consider the same metric as in the embedding space, and we change the metric of the embedding space?

Comment: My comment was not just intuition. And why would it be different with an isometrically embedded submanifold? The Hessian still depends on the partial derivative of the metric.

Comment: Because in that case the metric is the same in all tangent spaces, so maybe the derivative of the metric somehow vanishes and the two things are the same. If $P:E\to E$ is such that $\langle u, v \rangle' = \langle u, Pv \rangle$, then one can write $P_x = \mathrm{Proj}_x \circ P$ where $\mathrm{Proj}_x:E\to T_xM$ is the orthogonal projection w.r.t $\langle u, v \rangle$. Does this help?